# How to clear a text box after I make a selection in an select list before the page is submitted?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

So let me explain. I have a text box that is used to input the employee number you want to look for and thus look for it by employee number. I also have a select list in the same page which displays all the employees names and you can select the employee by name.

That being said I want to be able to clear the text box once I select an employee from the list. In my efforts to achieve this I was able to clear the text box once I selected the employee from the select list by appending a dynamic action to the select list BUT... this is happening after the page is submitted. The page is immediately submitted when I select an employee from the list. If the page is submitted first and then the text box is clear by the dynamic action it wont help me because it is submitting the number that was in the text box previously. I want to cover for the situation where the user writes the employee number in the text box and later on decides to use the list instead to look for an employee but it did so without clearing the text box first. If that happens it will look for 2 employees at once and I dont want that. What I want to happen is to first clear the textbox and then submit the page.

Here is a picture of my page designer in APEX:

[image]

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, to make it simpler, use `COALESCE`. It will return first non-empty item value, so you'd have such a report query:

```
select *
from emp
where empno = coalesce(:P42_SEARCH_FOR_EMP, :EMPLOYEE_H)
```

It means that

- if `P42_SEARCH_FOR_EMP` is selected, its return value will be used
- otherwise, `EMPLOYEE_H` will be used